# MVC4 httpException.GetHttpCode(); causing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localhost, global-asax

I had to restructure my whole application, from VS Express DB to using Visual Studio 2012.
I had to remove all the modals and re add them again.

Now when I try to run the application, it keeps falling over the Global.Asax.cs

It keeps throwing NullReferenceException    --> int exceptionType = httpException.GetHttpCode();

My Application does not even run, it seems like the localhost server is not even loading my website

Help please

```
protected void Application_Error()
        {

            if (Context.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
                ShowCustomErrorPage(Server.GetLastError());

        }
        private void ShowCustomErrorPage(Exception exception)
        {
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;
            if (exception != null)
            {
                exception = httpException;
            }

            else
            {

                exception = new HttpException(500, "Internal Server Error", exception);
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("Controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("fromAppErrorEvent", true);

            int exceptionType = httpException.GetHttpCode();

            switch (exceptionType)
            {


                case 403:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError403");
                    break;

                case 404:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "NotFound");
                    break;

                case 500:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError500");
                    break;

                default:
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "GeneralError");
                    routeData.Values.Add("httpStatusCode", httpException.GetHttpCode());
                    break;
            }



            IController controller = new Login.Controllers.ErrorController();
            controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the logic above `httpException` can be `null` - try changing your code to something like this:

```
HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException
    ?? new HttpException(500, "Internal Server Error", exception);

Response.Clear();
Server.ClearError();
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("Controller", "Error");
routeData.Values.Add("fromAppErrorEvent", true);

int exceptionType = httpException.GetHttpCode();
```